# Fixed Nav Issue

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a stick nav. However on doing so, the nav goes into the background.

I've set the position on the nav div like so,

```
.site-header {
    ...
    position: fixed;
}
```

However, this has worked as expected, as mentioned above. Is there anything else I should be adding, to ensure the div is ontop and fixed.

https://jsfiddle.net/fe6jc8nu/

Thanks,

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and ___the shortest code necessary___ to reproduce it ___in the question itself___. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried adding a z-index: 2;  or whatever level is in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z:index: 9;` to `.site-header` rule:

```
.site-header {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
}
```